# What is the fastest way to get notebook CellGroups / Cells structure?

Tags: notebooks, performance-tuning, cells

So the question is how to get this kind of information:

> [image]

from

> [image]

This is one of my ideas:

```
get = Function[notebook,
  Block[{i = 0, cells},
       cells = Cells[notebook]; 
       # /. _Cell :> cells[[++i]]       (*a*)
       ] & @ Block[{Cell, cells, i = 0},

      Cell[CellGroupData[c_, ___], ___] := c;
      First @ NotebookGet[#]
      ] & @ notebook
  ]
   (*Ad a: We are using ReplaceAll instead of Cell[___]:=cells[[++i]] because 
we want to avoid counting inline cells. We also have to do this in separate Block so
Cell[CellGroupData will be flat already.*)
```

But `NotebookGet` is not so fast, the bigger the notebook the slower, obviously. For help notebook it takes about 2 seconds. Far to much in my opinion.

```
get[help] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> [image]

On the other hand it is quite compact and deals well with `InlineCells`, nondefault `CellGrouping` or custom cell styles.

So is there faster alternative? It doesn't even have to deal with non standard cellgrouping etc.

Comment: Would the "internal cache information" at the end of the nb files be enough?

Comment: @Silvia I will take a closer look later but it seems like a good idea. I was not aware of that, thanks. :)

Comment: No problem :) I'm just not sure you want the CellObjects or just the outline structure. But any way there are CellIDs in the cache.

Comment: @Silvia yes, probably I need them inside but if I can get the outline faster it is already something :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your code has a bottleneck in `NotebookGet`, the only way to speed it up directly would be to speed up the latter. If your notebook exists on disk, you may try using something like this:

```
ClearAll[nbget];
nbget[nbfile_String?FileExistsQ] :=
   FirstCase[_Notebook]@ToHeldExpression@Import[nbfile, "String"];

nbget[nb_NotebookObject] :=
   With[{file = Quiet[NotebookFileName[nb], {NotebookFileName::nosv }]},
     nbget[file] /; file =!= $Failed
   ];
```

On my machine, it runs about 2-3 times faster than `NotebookGet`, and it seems to work correctly. Further speedup with your methods seems only possible if you write a custom parser that would be faster than `ToExpression`. This seems entirely possible, but certainly requires more work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Silvia`s suggestion I found even faster way:

```
<< AuthorTools`

NotebookFileOutline[EvaluationNotebook[]] ~ Do ~ {100} // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.564001, Null} (*big notebook, done 100 times!*)
> ```